# Presenting a Modal ViewController from a TableViewController lags

Tags: ios, multithreading, uitableview, cocoa-touch, modalviewcontroller

I have UITableViewController that needs to present a view controller modally when a cell is tapped. I'm using `didSelectRowAt` for this.

The modal view controller is a custom UIViewController subclass that has a `loadFromStoryboard()` class method to load it.

Sometimes when I tap the cell, the view controller is presented quickly without issue. However, other times it doesn't show until I, for instance, try to scroll on the tableview or tap another cell.

I'm guessing this is some sort of problem with threading. However, throughout my entire app, I never delegate a task to another thread or start another queue at all.

N.B.: I am using Swift 3.

**Update**

Here's the `loadFromStoryboard()` method:

```
class func loadFromStoryboard(particle: ParticleProtocol, isFavourite: Bool = false) -> ParticleDisplayViewController {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    if let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ParticleDisplayViewController") as? ParticleDisplayViewController {

        viewController.particle = particle
        viewController.isFavourite = isFavourite

        return viewController
    } else {
        fatalError("Can't find ParticleDisplayViewController in Main storyboard")
    }
}
```

And here is `didSelectRowAt` from my UITableViewController:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    switch indexPath.section {
    case 1:
        let isFavourite = ParticleStorageManager.standardModelParticleIsFavourite(index: indexPath.row)
        self.present(ParticleDisplayViewController.loadFromStoryboard(particle: standardModelParticles[indexPath.row], isFavourite: isFavourite), animated: true, completion: nil)
    case 0:
        let isFavourite = ParticleStorageManager.savedParticleIsFavourite(index: indexPath.row)
        self.present(ParticleDisplayViewController.loadFromStoryboard(particle: self.particles[indexPath.row], isFavourite: isFavourite), animated: true, completion: nil)
    default:
        self.contextKey = "AddingParticle"
        self.present(CreateParticleTableViewController.loadFromStoryboard(reciever: self), animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

`ParicleStorageManager` simply reads and writes data to the `UserDefaults`.

Here's `viewDidLoad()` from the modal view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.view.backgroundColor = .clear()

    self.particleViewContainer.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.particleViewContainer.addSubview(ParticleView(position: CGPoint.zero, width: particleViewContainer.width, particle: self.particle, isFavourite: self.isFavourite))

    propertiesTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white().withAlphaComponent(0.3)
    propertiesTableView.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
    propertiesTableView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black().cgColor
    self.propertiesTableView.blur()
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code that instantiates/presents the view controller? Sounds like you might be doing something there that's off the main thread.

Comment: @JohnMorrison updated.

Comment: @YoussefSami: Can u add the code for the `viewDidLoad` of the instantiated ViewController that you are presenting.

Comment: @YoussefSami: All seems good. You'll have to use breakpoints and NSLogs to find the exact line of code which is causing the delay in presenting.

Comment: @Nishant I did.. `didSelectRowAt` finishes execution completely without the modal view controller appearing.

Comment: @YoussefSami: You also have to put NSLogs in the viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear (if any) of the presenting view controller. U tried that?

Comment: @Nishant right, I just tried putting breakpoints. `viewDidLoad()` always gets called. However, on the times when the view controller delays to when I try to scroll `viewDidAppear()` only gets called when it actually displays.

Comment: @Nishant I was able to solve this by doing the presenting in a `OperationQueue.main().addOperation` block. Is this an optimal solution?

Comment: @YoussefSami: You are forcing the operation into the main thread. This is ok but should not be required in the first place. You still wont know the reason of why it was happening.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `self.present` from within `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` is the reason here as `UIPresentationController` may take time to find the layout from tableview row selection and causes a delay in presenting a new controller modally.

A better way to present is using the `DispatchQueue` on main thread. This way the delay can be avoided.

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
           //Your Presentation code should be called here.... 
   }
```